# Sharing a virtual method implementation

Tags: c#, design-patterns, mef

The example code is much simplified.  The gist is, we have a project that uses MEF extensively.  Every MEF based interface implements IPlugin:

```
public interface IPlugin
{
   ImplementationName ImplementationName {get;}
   bool TryProvide(FeatureName name);
}
public interface IFoo : IPlugin ...
public interface IBar : IPlugin ...
```

All the interfaces have an abstract base implementation

```
public abstract class FooBase : IFoo 
{
  public abstract ImplementationName ImplementationName {get;}
  protected virtual Regex FeaturePattern {get;}
  public virtual bool TryProvide(FeatureName name)
  {
      return name.ToString() == ImplementationName.ToString() 
        || (FeaturePattern != null && FeaturePattern.IsMatch(name.ToString()));
  }
...
}
```

All the abstract bases (currently) independently implement one of 2 algorithms.  One looks only at ImplementationName while the other includes the FeaturePattern test.  I'd like to centralize maintenance of the algorithms.

I'd be particularly interested in a way that doesn't expose the algorithm to direct use by the host application like an extension method to ImplementationName or FeatureName would.

Comment: Is it a failing of the C# language that a pattern for solving this problem doesn't exist or a poor design wanting a solution to a problem that need not exist.  I'm certainly open to modifying the  plugin identification mechanism if a better one exists.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to create a base class for your base classes. For instance:

```
public abstract class BazBase : IPlugin
{
    public abstract ImplementationName ImplementationName {get;}
    protected virtual Regex FeaturePattern {get;}
    public abstract TryProvide(FeatureName name);
    protected virtual bool ImplementationNameTest(FeatureName name)
    {
        return name.ToString() == ImplementationName.ToString();
    }
    protected virtual bool FeaturePatternTest(FeatureName name)
    {
        return FeaturePattern != null && FeaturePattern.IsMatch(name.ToString());
    }
}
```

Then you could have:

```
public abstract class FooBase : BazBase, IFoo
{
    public virtual bool TryProvide(FeatureName name)
    {
        return ImplementationNameTest(name) || FeaturePatternTest(name);
    }
}
```

Some of the syntax might be wrong, I'm not a C# programmer, but you get the idea.